# ParticleSystem doesn't play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can't figure out why ParticleSystem doesn't play.

I get my Debug working, its Instantiate gameobject, but can't see it playing.

what I'm missing here?

I have similar code for OoTriggerEnter and it works like a charm,

```
public static int levelValue = 1;
Text level;
public GameObject newLevelExplosion;

bool PlayP = false;


void Start()
{
   level = GetComponent<Text>();
   level.text = "Level:" + levelValue;
}


void Update()
{



    if (levelValue == 2 && !PlayP)
    {

            Debug.Log("Playing");

        GameObject particle7 = Instantiate(newLevelExplosion, 
this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        particle7.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();


        PlayP = false;

        particleSomething();

    }

}


public void particleSomething()

{
    PlayP = true;
}


}
```

Particle settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the particle system prefab. What state of Emission and Renderer parameters (true/false)?

Comment: does it play once and never again?? as your particleSomething sets it true, it will never play again

Comment: yes it supposed to play once, but nothing is happening, like I mentioned above I have almost the same script and particle system in different game object and it play perfectly fine. but its OnTriggerEnter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the settings you used on your ParticleSystem?
Also an advice for you; if the level.text only supposed to show what level you are on, you really don't need to set it each update.

Comment: please check my updated question with particle settings, 

Ps: thanks for advice, I change it to START.

Comment: Hmm have you tried to change the "Emission rate over time" and add a burst instead? I am wondering if your very short duration (0.1) can make it too quick to even manage to create any partivles before the duration is ended?

Also; have you checked if the particle plays in Scene view? since you are setting the position to the transforms position, it might be too close to the camera?